# Perl hex replacement (s///g) has no effect when used on an ISO file

Tags: perl, hex, iso9660

I am trying to install a Live Kali Linux on a USB without the two beeps at booting. I found [the fifth post in this thread](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?37280-kali-linux-2017-1-boot-menu-beep) that says:

> This can also depend on UEFI vs BIOS
>
> For BIOS you can use the following PERL script on the ISO file itself
>   and it will take care of any place ^G exists in the iso:
>
> ```
> perl -p -i -e 's;\x6d\x65\x6e\x75\x07;\x6d\x65\x6e\x75\x20;g' your-kali.iso
> ```
>
> The beep was added for accessibility to the UEFI boot menu as well so
>   you may still get the beep. To remove that you must edit grub.cfg and
>   comment out or remove the following two lines:
>
> *insmode play*
>   *play 960 440 1 0 4 440 1*
>
> I used live build to make the changes to grub.cfg, generated the iso,
>   and then ran the perl script prior to flashing to the usb.

I managed to delete the (x07) byte for BIOS with the given Perl script, so I tried the same thing with "*insmode play play 60 440 1 0 4 440 1*" (I opened grub.cfg in a hex editor, copied the hex of this string, 696E736D6F6420706C61790A706C61792039363020343430203120302034203434302031, and put 20 in the place of every byte).

I ran this script `perl -p -i -e 's;\x69\x6e\x73\x6d\x6f\x64\x20\x70\x6c\x61\x79\x0a\x70\x6c\x61\x79\x20\x39\x36\x30\x20\x34\x34\x30\x20\x31\x20\x30\x20\x34\x20\x34\x34\x30\x20\x31;\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20;g' your-kali.iso`.

But the string is still in the iso.

Why does it not get replaced?

Comment: What is so wrong with the beeps that makes it worth this effort?

Comment: @mob I don't want to disturb people around me or myself.

Comment: @Nesa: Your "people" must be hugely sensitive to be disturbed by a couple of beeps. Do you reboot the system multiple times per hour? This sounds suspiciously like you're trying to access a system without anyone knowing.

Comment: @Borodin no it's just common courtesy, I don't want to disturb a company's employees while I am taking down their system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a line at a time, which is defined as a sequence of byte up until the line feed (inclusive). So `$_` is never going to have a line feed anywhere but at the end.

```
perl -i -pe'
   s/^i(?=nsmode play$)/#/;
   s/^p(?=lay 960 440 1 0 4 440 1$)/#/;
' your-kali.iso
```

That comments out the lines independently. If you want to replace them as a set, you'll need a buffer.

```
perl -i -pe'
   if (/^insmode play$/) {
      $buf = $_;
      $_ = "";
      next;
   }

   $_ = $buf . $_;
   $buf = "";
   s/^insmode play\nplay 960 440 1 0 4 440 1\n/#nsmode play\n#lay 960 440 1 0 4 440 1\n/;

   END { print $buf }
' your-kali.iso
```

Answer (score 1):

`perl -p -e CODE` generally runs the specified CODE on each line of the input, where lines (on POSIX-y systems) are separated by newline (`\x0a`) characters, so this code will not allow you to make substitutions where the search pattern contains `\x0a`.

My approach (and this is Perl, so there are many ways to do this) would be more like

```
perl -p -i -e '$_="" if $_ eq "insmod play\n" || 
               $_ eq "play 960 440 1 0 4 440 1\n"' your-kali.iso
```

This replaces the input line with the empty string when the line matches one of two target patterns (that is, removes them from the output, not replaces them with strings of spaces).

Comment: but wouldn't this remove "insmode play \n" even without "play 960" on the following line? I think I need to write back the same number of bytes as I deleted

Comment: @mob, You can't change the size of the .iso like that.